# Function instead of loop in php CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I have bulk data in the form of array and i want to show the data on the view, when i show the data by using **foreach()** it takes very huge time and some time i gives **500** Error , in python programming language there are so many functions that allows the developer to show array data very fast. is there is a function such like python programming language that will show the bulk amount of  very data quickly. the following is the array example
kindly download the sample array file through the following link

[Array File](https://ufile.io/e1pdtv7u)

Comment: This is not the right approach which you are following. You should display less records and provide pagination to the user.

Comment: [PHP Array Functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php)